# Access-Control-Allow-Origin axios request error - CORS

Tags: javascript, rest, express, post, axios

I have a problem with CORS while sending POST request:

Here is my code:

```
import axios from 'axios'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8084',
})


export const postTip = async (payload) => {
  try {
    const { data } = await api.post(`post-tip`, payload);
    return data;
  } catch (e) {
    return [];
  }
};
```

I have found that I need to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in headers, and I did it in 2 ways. First one:

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:8084',
  headers: {
    post: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true
    }
  }
})
```

And the second one:

```
const { data } = await api.post(`post-tip`, payload, {
      headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true
      }
    });
```

Both of them work and in request header I can see this line `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: true`. But I still get this error, so, what's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error from your backend, you use axios post from front-end, but you need to set header "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": true on your backend.

Comment: Actually, you're right. I installed `cors` on back-end and it seems to work, but now I'm getting `POST http://localhost:8084/post-tip 404 (Not Found)`

Answer (score 0):

this error is probably coming from the server.
Are you trying to reach your own api?
If you do the error might be there.

I see you tagged express so please refer to this page it should contain all the information you need

http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html